# How to find all interfaces in class that extends other classes with other interfaces using reflection in java

Tags: java, class, reflection, interface, find

for example I have:

```
interface IA;
interface IB;

public class B implements IB;
public class A extends B implements IA;
```

how can I find in `A.class` all implemented interfaces in extended `B.class` too?, method `Class<?> getInterfaces()` returns only interfaces in `A` class not in extended class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop, calling `getInterfaces` on `A`, then use [`getSuperclass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--) to get its super class, and then do that again, etc., until `getSuperclass` returns `null`.

```
List<Class<?>> list = new LinkedList<Class<?>>();
Class<?> cls = A.class;
while (cls != null) {
    // Call cls.getInterfaces, add result to list
    // ...

    // Go to its parent
    cls = cls.getSuperclass();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the [superclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--) and its interfaces

```
Class<?> clazz = A.class;
Class<?>[] interfaces = clazz.getSuperclass().getInterfaces();
// add interfaces to some larger list
```

Do this recursively until the superclass is `Object` or `null`.

> If this `Class` represents either the `Object` class, an interface, a
>   primitive type, or `void`, then `null` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

#### Guava Solution:

#### Proxies.java

```
public static TypeToken.TypeSet getTypes(@Nonnull final Class cls)
{
    return TypeToken.of(cls).getTypes();
}

public static TypeToken subClassesOf(@Nonnull final Class superClass, @Nonnull final Set<TypeToken> typeTokens)
{
    for (final TypeToken tt : typeTokens)
    {
        if (tt.getRawType().getSuperclass() == null)
        {
            return tt;
        }
        {
            return subClassesOf(superClass, tt.getTypes().interfaces());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is how you call it:

```
    final Class superClass = // super class you want the subclass Interface of
    final TypeToken tt = TypeToken.of(superClass.getClass());
    final TypeToken tti = Proxies.subClassesOf(superClass.getClass(),tt.getTypes().interfaces());
    final Class subTypeInterface = tti.getRawType();
```

I use this to pull `Annotations` from a `DyanmicProxy` instance where the `Annotations` are on the specialized `SubType` interface.